# GPS ping in the intervals

Tags: swift, gps, cllocationmanager, ping

Is it possible in IOS swift to get gps ping after `x minutes`, `x miles` and with `x angle` ?

`x angle` it is a degree turn, so if you turn your mobile by 100 degree then ping going to be executed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach is probably to build your own wrapper around `CLLocationManager` where you track the 'origin' time, position and angle and trigger either a callback or `NSNotification` to the consumer of this wrapper once you exceed your specified values.